# compare and merge multiple files the text file using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, merge, text-files, streamreader

I have a multiple text files that I need to merge. but I need to compare the reference number before merge it.

below is the text file

```
Text 1    
001Email
002Video
003SocialNetwork

Text 2
001Gmail
001Yahoo
002Youtube
002Metacafe
003Facebook
003Myspace

Text 3
www.gmail.com001
www.yahoo.com001
www.youtube.com002
www.myspace.com002
www.facebook.com003
www.myspace.com003


Output


001Email
001Gmail
www.gmail.com001
001Yahoo
wwww.yahoo.com001
002Video
002Youtube
www.youtube.com002
002Metacafe
www.metacafe.com002
003SocialNetwork
003Facebook
www.facebook.com003
003Myspace
www.myspace.com003
```

What will be the fastest way to deal it read line by line to compare. the text file consist of thousand of line

Answer (score 0):

Here's what might possibly be an overly complex solution. The comments in the code should explain everything hopefully. The output doesn't match exactly what you have because I don't know how much order is important for everything. It sorts everything first by the reference number and then by the text portion of the string (excluding `www.`). The results you posted were in reference number order and then file parsing order and then alphabetical (002Metacafe came after 002Video). Let me know if that's important.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ''//List of files to process
        Dim Files As New List(Of String)
        Files.Add(Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "Text1.txt"))
        Files.Add(Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "Text2.txt"))
        Files.Add(Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "Text3.txt"))

        ''//Will hold the current line being read
        Dim Line As String

        ''//Holds our main collection of data
        Dim MyData As New List(Of Data)

        ''//Loop through each file
        For Each F In Files
            ''//Open the file for reading
            Using FS As New FileStream(F, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
                Using SR As New StreamReader(FS)

                    ''//Read each line
                    Line = SR.ReadLine()
                    Do While Line IsNot Nothing
                        ''//The data constructor handles parsing of the line
                        MyData.Add(New Data(Line))
                        ''//Read next line
                        Line = SR.ReadLine()
                    Loop

                End Using
            End Using
        Next

        ''//Our data implements IComparable(Of Data) so we can just sort the list
        MyData.Sort()

        ''//Output our data
        For Each D In MyData
            Trace.WriteLine(D)
        Next

        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Data
    Implements IComparable(Of Data)

    ''//Our RegEx pattern for looking for a string that either starts or ends with numbers
    Private Shared ReadOnly Pattern As String = "^(?<RefStart>\d+)?(?<Text>.*?)(?<RefEnd>\d+)?$"

    Public Text As String                      ''//The _text_ portion of the data
    Public Reference As String                 ''//The reference number stored as text
    Public ReferenceAtStart As Boolean         ''//Whether the reference number was found at the start or end of the line
    Public ReadOnly Property ReferenceAsNum() As Integer  ''//Numeric version of the reference number for sorting
        Get
            Return Integer.Parse(Me.Reference)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property TextComparable() As String   ''//Remove the www for sorting
        Get
            Return Me.Text.Replace("www.", "")
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal line As String)
        ''//Sanity check
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("line")

        ''//Parse the line
        Dim M = Regex.Match(line, Pattern)
        If M Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("Line does not conform to expected pattern")

        ''//If the RefStart has a value then the number is at the beginning of the string
        If M.Groups("RefStart").Success Then
            Me.ReferenceAtStart = True
            Me.Reference = M.Groups("RefStart").Value
        Else ''//Otherwise its at the end
            Me.ReferenceAtStart = False
            Me.Reference = M.Groups("RefEnd").Value
        End If
        Me.Text = M.Groups("Text").Value
    End Sub

    Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As Data) As Integer Implements System.IComparable(Of Data).CompareTo
        ''//Compare the reference numbers first
        Dim Ret = Me.ReferenceAsNum.CompareTo(other.ReferenceAsNum)
        ''//If they are the same then compare the strings
        If Ret = 0 Then Ret = String.Compare(Me.TextComparable, other.TextComparable, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

        Return Ret
    End Function
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        ''//Reproduce the original string
        If Me.ReferenceAtStart Then
            Return String.Format("{0}{1}", Me.Reference, Me.Text)
        Else
            Return String.Format("{1}{0}", Me.Reference, Me.Text)
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Hi Chris  I copy and paste your code somehow there are error list such as Public Property Reference As String   "Statement cannot appear within a property body end of property assumed"
if String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)  "IsNullOrWhiteSpace is not a member of a string"
Me.ReferenceAtStart = True    "ReferenceAtStart is not a member of combined.data"   Did I miss to put a reference?

Comment: Looks like you're using VS2008, my code was for VS2010, I've updated my code.

Comment: Hi Chris you code is amazing. thank you.. just another request word 001Email, 002Video, and 003SocialNetwork is like a header means should write first before the MetaCafe and YouTube. In addition if I need to add more text file this program can handle it?

Comment: Hi Chris, additional Information I need to write the text file according sequence of reading the text file. let say text1 first then text2 and text3.

Comment: @user801207, the data that you've posted above is nice and clean and if all of your data looks like that then it shouldn't be too hard to modify my code. The data in the first file is a category, the second is basically a brand name and the third represents the website for that brand name. In your sample data there's a one-to-one mapping from brand name to website name, in other words for any `BRAND` the website is `www.brand.com`. Is this rule true for all of your data? One exception that comes to mind is the brand `Coke` with a website of `www.coca-cola.com`.

Comment: If its not uniform then it comes down to an arbitrary human decision which I can't automate without knowing all of your possible rules.

Comment: Hi chris yes the data have a "-"

Comment: @user801207, sorry, I don't understand your last comment

Comment: @chris The exception the data consist of "-" dash